# iphone 4 high res startup image

Tags: iphone, mobile-safari

I have a fullscreen iphone web app that has a startup screen that works. I am trying to figure out how to get this image looking better on the iP4, but if I change the size from 320x460 it simply will not load.

Anyone find a solution yet?

Thanks,
Peter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have a second image with the ending `@2x`.

For example, if your startup image is named `Default.png`, your high-rest image should be named `Default@2x.png`

Comment: I tried this also. In my case it ignores the high-res image and uses the low res one no matter what screen is being used. Can you confirm that the required resolution for the @2x file is 640x920 ?

Comment: simply adding @2x doesnt fix this, im still trying to find out how.

Comment: @OwenMelbourne do you have both image files, one for each resolution (320x480 and 640x960)?